# QTKit playing protected video (HDCP) in mac os

Tags: macos, qtkit, hdcp

Is it possible for QTKit or AVPlayer to play protected video with HDCP.
I know that QuickTIme player plays a video (for example, a downloaded video from itunes),
but when I use QTMovie, he refuses to play this file.
What might be the way to solve this problem?
And is possible to enabled hdcp for non protected video files?

Answer (score 0):

You can only play HDCP protected content as long as your hardware allows. That means that, there should be HDCP keys burned in one of the chips on your mainboard. When there is a HDCP enabled monitor plugged and when you play a movie on your device, the keys burned in your hardware are going to be used during handshaking between your device (source) and the monitor (sink). If you have no keys, there will be no handshake and you will never be able to de-crypt HDCP encrypted content on your device. Hope this helps.